# Does a classical wave detect compact dimensions?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

Please excuse if the question is too easy; I'm just not familiar enough with PDEs.

I'd like to understand a little bit *classical* implications of "adding compact dimensions" in Physics, that is, what would change if one considers *classical* Physics in $M\times \mathbb{R}^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $M$ is compact and "small".

Here's a handwaving example of what I'm looking for. It's well known that a classical wave "detects" the parity of the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$: only for odd $n$ the wave originated at a point source would reach the observer once. Now, what would happen in $M\times \mathbb{R}^1$ when $M=S^1\times S^1$ of diameter $\epsilon$ when the distance between the source and the observer $l$ is much larger than $\epsilon$? 
One could replace a single point source in $M\times \mathbb{R}^1$ with a 2-d square grid of sources at distances $\epsilon$ from each other in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with the observer at distance $l >> \epsilon$ from the plane containing the grid. Then the waves from different sources in the grid would reach the observer at different times. This makes the point source wave in $M\times \mathbb{R}^1$ act *qualitatively* different from what one expect from a point source in $\mathbb{R}^1$: one would, er, "feel the disturbance in the force" long after one should, even if $M$ is "small".

My question is something like this: assuming that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a reasonable model of a classical space, what makes it possible to consider $M\times \mathbb{R}^3$ and still arrive to reasonable conclusions?

Comment: Why a 2-d square grid of sources rather than an infinite array of sources?

Comment: @AndréHenriques: unrolling $S^1\times S^1$ with a single point source into $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a 2-d grid of sources, with adjacent ones at the distance equal to $S^1$ length $\epsilon$.

Comment: The standard way to compare the $M \times \mathbb{R}^3$ case to the $\mathbb{R}^3$ one is to expand the wave field in modes of the compact factor (simple Fourier modes, in your example). Each mode coefficient will satisfy a PDE only on $\mathbb{R}^3$, possibly with extra terms that are proportional to $\epsilon$. All quantitative or qualitative differences between $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $M\times \mathbb{R}^3$ are then expected to be small of order $\epsilon$, or some higher power of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 4):

The compactification introduces periodic boundary conditions, and therefore the momentum in the extra dimension can take only discrete values. A particle that propagates in the extra compactified dimension then is associated with a ladder of momenta in our three-dimensional world. In a scattering experiment, one would observe this ladder as copies of the particle with different mass (because of the energy-momentum relation), socalled Kaluza-Klein copies. See [On Kaluza-Klein States from Large Extra Dimensions.](http://xxx.lanl.gov/abs/hep-ph/9811350v4)

For wave propagation in extra dimensions without compactification (where still we would only be able to observe three dimensions), see [Pulse propagation in a hyper-lattice.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3636)

Comment: The question is about classical physics. When you refer to momentum, is that really interchangeable with wavenumber (inverse wavelength)?

Comment: @BenCrowell --- in the case of a classical wave, for momentum read wavenumber (discretized at $k_n$), and for mass read cutoff frequency $\omega_n=ck_n$, so that the dispersion relation in three-dimensional space is $\omega^2=(ck)^2 +\omega_n^2$.